# Convert String to Turtle.FilePath

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

How can I convert a concatenated `String` to a Turtle `FilePath`? For instance, the following program tries to read some text files, concatenate them into a new one and remove the old ones. It does not seem to work although the `OverloadedStrings` extension is enabled:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Turtle
import Turtle.Prelude
import qualified Control.Foldl as L

main :: IO ()
main = do
  params <- getArgs
  let n             = read $ params !! 0
      k             = read $ params !! 1
  -- Some magic is done here
  -- After a while, read generated .txt files and concatenate them
  files <- fold (find (suffix ".txt") ".") L.list
  let concat = cat $ fmap input files
  output (show n ++ "-" ++ show k ++ ".txt") concat
  -- Remove old .txt files
  mapM_ rm files
```

The error thrown is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Turtle.FilePath’
                with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the first argument of ‘output’, namely
      ‘(show n ++ "-" ++ show k ++ ".txt")’
```

Switching to `output "example.txt" concat` would just work fine. Isn't `String` just a type alias of `[Char]`?

Comment: `fromString` listed [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.2.8/docs/Turtle.html) might work.

Comment: But you probably should be using turtle's `Format` interface found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.2.8/docs/Turtle-Format.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String` *is* just an alias to `[Char]`, yes.

You see the bit where it says `{-# OverloadedStrings #-}`? What that does is make the compiler automatically insert `fromString` everywhere you write a *literal string*. It does *not* automatically insert it anywhere else you touch a string, only when it's a string constant.

If you manually call `fromString` on the result of the whole expression for building the path, that will probably fix it. (In particular, the `show` function always returns `String`, not any kind of overloaded string.)

Comment: I understand, thank you for reminding me this. And yes, using `fromString` automatically fixed the type error.